# from buffered image to data output stream

Tags: java, file

I want to write to a data output stream a buffered image.

Whatever I tried doesn't work.

For example:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

      try {
          dos.writeByte((DataBufferByte) image.getData().getDataBuffer());
      }finally {
          dos.close();
      }

      baos.writeTo(os);
```

I can't make the line `dos.writeByte((DataBufferByte) image.getData().getDataBuffer());` to work.

Right now, it shows : `the method writeByte(int) in the type DataOutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (DataBufferByte)`

Answer (score 0):

The method [`writeByte`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeByte(int)) take a single `int`, not a `DataBufferByte` as parameter:

> Writes out a byte to the underlying output stream as a 1-byte value. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by 1.

So your code can't compile.

Note that also taking an int it can't accept values over the size of 1 byte.

You need to extract the bytes array of the DataBufferByte and you can use the method [`write(byte\[\] b, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int)) to write them.

Comment: So, there is no way of writting a buffered image to data output stream?

Comment: Could you please provide an example in my case?I am a little bit lost here!Thanks!